# Reading One Line from a File in UTF-16 Format

Tags: java, utf-8

I have some files generated from a script that provide information about various computers. The txt files are in UTF-8, however, there is one line that is in UTF-16 format. How should I go about reading this line from the file?

P.S. I'm trying to write a program to parse out all of these files and recompile them into one collective .csv file.

I have tried reading the file with a `bufferedReader` and `Scanner`, however this one line is the only one I am having trouble with. Most of the code I have found online for reading UTF-16 is for the entire file, which is not completely in UTF-16.

//How the line looks when opened in Notepad.

```
S e r i a l N u m b e r     5 C G 8 X X X X X X
```

//How the line looks when opened in Notepad++ with "nul" values in between each character.

```
S e r i a l N u m b e r     

 5 C G 8 X X X X X X
```

My code can pick up parts of the string, but the format of it is on multiple lines and Java doesn't recognize the characters in between each letter or number.

Comment: Are you saying a single file contains some text in UTF-16 *and* some text in UTF-8? If so, make this more obvious in both your title and the body of the Question. And point out this flaw to the publisher of the data.

Comment: Open a handle/stream/whatever to the file and read from it as UTF-8 until you reach the problematic line. Then open a second handle/stream/whatever to the same file, seek it to the byte offset of the problematic line, and read the line as UTF-16. Then seek the first handle/stream to the byte offset after the line, and continue reading the rest of the file as UTF-8.

Answer (score 4):

You can try like this.

```
File infile = new File("/someFileInutf16.txt");
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(infile);
 Reader in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-16");
```

Comment: I'll give that a try. Thanks.

Comment: I gave this a try, I'm sure I've messed something up, but I setup a simple test to use the code you suggested and see how it works. My output just prints a bunch of these "?"  "†" characters. Any suggestions for what could be wrong? I haven't ever used the InputStreamReader before.

Comment: If you are using any ide like eclipse or intellij, change the character set.

Comment: I tried changing the character encoding to each of the option, none of them work as expected. I'm using Eclipse by the way. I went to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace and change the option there as well as the default encoding option in Content Types as well. Were these the settings you mentioned?

Comment: Why would this actually help? Where is the explanation? If the file is UTF-8 and only one line is UTF-16, opening a stream in UTF-16 mode will not properly the rest lines.

Comment: After doing some more testing, I found I was wrong about the encoding of the text. Turn's out, the entire text file is in UTF-8. I am able to read the file in its entirety, but I cannot get a String from the lines I need. The "nul" characters that show up when I open the file in Notepad++ seem to prevent me from being able to do this. I used a scanner to read the file and set it to UTF-8 encoding. I'm not sure how to capture this data, if all I am able to do with it is print it to the console. Do I need to convert the entire file to another encoding or does anyone know of another way?